# C# class constructor assigning to 'this'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, constructor

I have a 'naïve' question.

With the following sample code:

```
public class ThisClass
{
    public int ThisClassID { get; set; }
    public string ThisValue { get; set;}

    public ThisClass()
    {
    }

    public ThisClass(int thisClassID)
    {
        using (MyContext dbContext = new MyContext())
        {
            this = dbContext.CaseNotes.Find(thisClassID);
        }
    }
}
```

And, of course, I get the error `Cannot assign to 'this' because it is read-only`

The only two ways of solving this that I know of are to have a static method, or to assign to each property separately.

Is there any way of creating a simple constructor that returns database entities into `this`?

**UPDATE**
Both answers below are *correct* but I can only accept one. There was some interesting discussion on the use of factories and repository patterns that were sadly deleted when a potential answer was deleted. Arguments were equally balanced both for and against with some pointing out the the Entity Framework itself is a factory that uses a repository pattern. The question itself had three upvotes and two downvotes.

The answer seems to be that there is no single answer.

Comment: so your `MyContext` already returns `ThisClass` instances right? ... Why would you copy those yet again?

Comment: This is a sample, non-real world example. It's not meant to work! I'm looking for a general solution to creating objects. Persistence is not the issue!

Comment: the -1 is not form me ... not every comment is connected with downvotes - indeed in the C# part people downvoting rarely care to comment

Comment: General solution would be to create a factory class and instanciate objects  of  ThisClass through factory and not with constructor.

Comment: IMO Factories are unneeded abstractions in 99.9% - and indeed outside older MS stuff you don't see Factories to often in modern code :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at [*AutoMapper*](http://automapper.org/), and your code could look as follows:

```
// Somewhere in your application/service initialization class and in some method...
Mapper.CreateMap<ThisClass, ThisClass>();

public class ThisClass
{
    public int ThisClassID { get; set; }
    public string ThisValue { get; set;}

    public ThisClass()
    {
    }

    public ThisClass(int thisClassID)
    {
        using (MyContext dbContext = new MyContext())
        {
            Mapper.Map(dbContext.CaseNotes.Find(thisClassID), this);
        }
    }
}
```

BTW it sounds like a bad idea. I wouldn't populate a domain object inside its own constructor.

This is a good responsibility [for the repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way of creating a simple constructor that returns database entities into this?

In practice no. In theory you can make the type a `struct`. Then, the code should compile. You can assign to this in a struct.

Probably, you should not use a constructor at all. Create a factory method that simply returns the result from Find.

One unchangeable fact about constructors is that they create a fresh object every time. I don't think you want that here. You probably want to preserve the existing object instance and its identity.

Comment: Using structs for database entities sounds like a recipe for disaster... It will  eat up the memory in no time. As you say, factory method should be the better way, ideally using the repository pattern internally.